# font-face does not work locally

Tags: asp.net, html, css, font-face

I have been using `@font-face` for a while now and have not had any issues when viewing my files online. But `@font-face` has never worked locally.

I don't understand why I cannot get `@font-face` to work locally. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate for my dev.

CSS:

```
/* Include Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationRegular';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.svg#SansationRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationLight';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.svg#SansationLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationBold';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.svg#SansationBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationLightLightItalic';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationLightLightItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationItalic';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationBoldItalic';
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

/* Set Fonts */
a, p, li, text, label, input, submit, textarea/* DEPRECATED:, #PositionPayRange*/ {
    font-family: 'SansationLight';
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .PositionPayRange {
    font-family: 'SansationBold';
}

/* Font sizing */
a, p, li, label {
    font-size: small;

}

/* Set Font Colors */
a, p, li, text, label, input {
    color: #111111;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #444444;
}
```

Can someone please explain why it works perfectly fine on the server, but *never locally*?

It does not matter which browser, or which version of a browser I use. Same results.

Edit:

My directory structure is:

```
root/
   Shared/
      Assets/
         Fonts/
            *fonts are in here.*
         CSS/
            * css files are in here. *
   Home.cshtml
```

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Comment: If you use `localhost/somesite` it will look into `localhost` while you are using `url('/Shared')`. Localhost becomes your root directory

Comment: I updated the question to include the directory structure.

Comment: @Morpheus where should I put the `localhost/somesite` bit?

Comment: @Joey use full path when you are working on localhost. Create another css and check if host is localhost then include your new css. Just remove `/` like this -> `src('Shared/)` if your `Home.cshtml` file is in same level as `Shared` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your current directory structure.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationRegular';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.svg#SansationRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationLight';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light-webfont.svg#SansationLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationBold';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold-webfont.svg#SansationBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationLightLightItalic';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Light_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationLightLightItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationItalic';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SansationBoldItalic';
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../Fonts/Sansation_Bold_Italic-webfont.svg#SansationBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: @Joey What is the major change in this except ../ ??

Comment: @Sowmya `Shared/Assets/` has been completely removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try path like this

```
src: url('../Shared/Assets/Fonts/Sansation_Regular-webfont.eot');
```

Comment: sorry that did not work. I have tried that ages ago. I have tried with 1 and two and 3 dots. No difference.